# CMake - не линкуется libconfig

Tags: c++, cmake

Пытаюсь построить проект с библиотекой libconfig - не линкуется.
Ошибки вида:

```
/var/deadBranch/nginx-instaban/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `libconfig::Config::Config()'
/var/deadBranch/nginx-instaban/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `libconfig::Config::readFile(char const*)'
```

CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(nginx-instaban)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -lconfig++ -lconfig")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp strFuncs.h banMgr.h banMgr.cpp banMgr.h nginxConfigReader.cpp nginxConfigReader.h IpParser.h IpHashTableGeneric.cpp IpHashTableGeneric.h BanRecord.h IpParser.cpp BinaryOps.h CheckIpHashTable.cpp CheckIpHashTable.h Configuration.cpp Configuration.h)
add_executable(nginx-instaban ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Установил libconfig++-dev и libconfig++8-dev еще зачем-то.

Comment: Пакеты `*-dev` — это объектные и заголовочные файлы, нужные для сборки программ, использующих библиотеку из соответствующего не-`*-dev` пакета.

Answer (score 3):

сделайте cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON, чтобы увидеть актуальную строку компиляции

скорее всего вы не прилинковали саму библиотеку в

`target_link_libraries(nginx-instaban config)`

Вот [здесь](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libconfig++-dev/filelist) к примеру, мы можем видеть `.a` и `.so` файлы:

```
/usr/include/libconfig.h++
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconfig++.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconfig++.so
```

Значит это не header-only библиотека, значит ее надо линковать

Answer (score 2):

Используйте механизм поиска зависимостей, который предоставляет CMake. Пример файла конфигурации поиска - [FindLibConfig.cmake](https://github.com/schnorr/pajeng/blob/master/cmake/FindLibConfig.cmake).

Пример использования:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(nginx-instaban)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")

set(SOURCE_FILES ...)
add_executable(nginx-instaban ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(Config REQUIRED)
find_package(Config++ REQUIRED)
if (LIBCONFIG_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(nginx-instaban ${LIBCONFIG_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(nginx-instaban ${LIBCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```