# Неопределенная ссылка на libconfig. Не подключается libconfig

Tags: c++, cmake, include, lib

пытаюсь подключить к проекту libconfig с помощью cmake, не получается, вот ошибки и сам cmake
Устанавливал вот так: `sudo apt install libconfig++-dev`

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(httpserver)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/local/include")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -L/usr/local/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -pthread -lconfig++")

set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/user/CPP_libs/boost_1_75_0/")
set(BOOST_LIBRARIES "/home/user/CPP_libs/boost_1_75_0/stage/lib/")

SET(SOURCE main.cpp httpserver.cpp httpserver.h message_handler.cpp)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)  # only find static libs
set(Boost_USE_DEBUG_LIBS        OFF)  # ignore debug libs and
set(Boost_USE_RELEASE_LIBS      OFF)  # only find release libs
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED     OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)

find_package(Boost 1.68 REQUIRED)

if(Boost_FOUND)
   include_directories(SYSTEM ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

add_executable(httpserver ${SOURCE})

target_link_libraries(httpserver config)
target_link_libraries(httpserver ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})
```

ошибки:

```
usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/httpserver.dir/main.cpp.o: в функции «HttpServer::~HttpServer()»:
/home/user/httpserver/httpserver.h:31: неопределённая ссылка на «libconfig::Config::~Config()»
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/httpserver.dir/httpserver.cpp.o: в функции «HttpServer::HttpServer()»:
/home/user/httpserver/httpserver.cpp:16: неопределённая ссылка на «libconfig::Config::Config()»
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/httpserver/httpserver.cpp:16: неопределённая ссылка на «libconfig::Config::~Config()»
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/httpserver.dir/httpserver.cpp.o: в функции «HttpServer::HttpServer(char const*)»:
```

Comment: Вероятный [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550890/176217).

Comment: config и config++ - это разные библиотеки